# What does "what" mean in this sentence?

Tags: conjugations

In the pilot episode of Breaking Bad, in one scene one character (Hank) says that:

> - Glock 22, that's my daily carry okay? **I mean, unless you're talking, what, plus P plus loads, you can forget the nine mil, alright?**

I couldn't quiet understand what he's saying. "What" is a conjugative word here but I don't get what place it does put "plus p plus loads" in.

Answer (score 2):

"What" in this context is an interjection, grammatically similar to "like" in sentences such as:

> He's been driving, like, one hundred miles per hour or so.

It doesn't impact the interpretation of the sentence, you can read it the same as if "what" wasn't there:

> I mean, unless you're talking plus P plus loads, you can forget the nine mil, alright?

It just underscores that Hank is reaching for a somewhat exaggerated scenario.

(Also, "plus P plus loads" refers to a [type of ammunition with a higher bullet velocity](http://www.firearmtutorials.com/index.php/ammunition/what_is_-p_and_-p))